# Mongoose: Add more items to existing object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using Mongoose, How can I add more items to an object without replacing existing ones?

```
 User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { userId: 0 },
  { userObjects: { newItem: value } }
 );
```

The problem with above code is that it clears whatever was there before and replaces it with newItem when I wanted it just to add another item to userObjects(Like push function for javascript arrays).

Comment: Is your `userObjects` an array? Can you share your schema?

Comment: Have a look at my most recent answer in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40741373/) for pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use dot notation to specify the field to update/add particular fields in an embedded document.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { userId: 0 },
  { "userObjects.newerItem": newervalue } }
);
```

or

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { userId: 0 },
  { "$set":{"userObjects.newerItem": newervalue } }
);
```

[image]

or Use $mergeObjects aggregation operator to update the existing obj by passing new objects

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  {"userId":0},
  [{"$set":{
    "userObjects":{
      "$mergeObjects":[
        "$userObjects",
        {"newerItem":"newervalue","newestItem":"newestvalue"}
      ]
    }
  }}]
)
```

Comment: this will update data in `userObjects.newerItem`. in my case I need to append the data to the existing object. like `$post` using in array

Comment: That is not true. Please try it. This will update the object to `{“userObjects”: {“newItem”:”value”, “newerItem”:”newvalue”}}` - example here - https://mongoplayground.net/p/SRdoAn4LG9N

Comment: Also added another aggregation based update option where you can pass the object itself without needing to list the each key value pair.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, i am guessing `userObjects` is an array.

You can try `$push` to insert items into the `array`.

```
 User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { userId: 0 },
  { $push : {"userObjects": { newItem: value } }},
  {safe :true , upsert : true},function(err,model)
  {
      ...
  });
```

For more info, read [MongoDB $push reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/).

Hope it helps you. If you had provided the schema, i could have helped better.

Answer (score 1):

Just create new collection called `UserObjects` and do something like this.

```
UserObject.Insert({ userId: 0, newItem: value }, function(err,newObject){

});
```

Whenever you want to get these user objects from a user then you can do it using monogoose's [query population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to populate parent objects with related data in other collections. If not, then your best bet is to just make the `userObjects` an array.